# Keeping the dimensionality of image data stack in rgb2gray transformation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimension

I have 4D RGB image_data[image, height, width, channel], in my case the dimensions are (x, 32, 32, 3) and I would like to convert these images to grayscale so that I have still 4D so that my dimensions are (x, 32, 32, 1).

I found a very simple rgb2gray transformation:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
```

The problem with this one is that it returns me (x, 32, 32), so I lose one dimension.

Now the solution in for loops that I could think of is following and it works:

```
def rgb2gray(images):
    gray_images = []
    for image in images:
        gray_image = []
        for size in image:
            gray_size = []
            for channels in size:
                channel = [np.dot(channels, [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])]
                gray_size.append(channel)
            gray_image.append(gray_size)
        gray_images.append(gray_image)
    return np.array(gray_images)
```

Now, I wonder if there is some more magical way to achieve the same result and if there exists a wizard who can show it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) or [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) or [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) or [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.dot(images,[0.299, 0.587, 0.114])[...,None]
np.tensordot(images,[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],axes=((-1),(-1)))[...,None]
np.matmul(images, [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])[...,None]
np.einsum('ijkl,l->ijk',images, [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])[...,None]
```

Sample run to verify shapes -

```
In [41]: images = np.random.randint(0,255,(10,32,32,3))

In [42]: np.dot(images,[0.299, 0.587, 0.114])[...,None].shape
Out[42]: (10, 32, 32, 1)

In [43]: np.tensordot(images,[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],axes=((-1),(-1)))[...,None].shape
Out[43]: (10, 32, 32, 1)

In [44]: np.matmul(images, [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])[...,None].shape
Out[44]: (10, 32, 32, 1)

In [45]: np.einsum('ijkl,l->ijk',images, [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])[...,None].shape
Out[45]: (10, 32, 32, 1)
```

Looking back at your question, you had `rgb2gray(rgb)` return `(n,32,32)` shaped array. So, the only modification you needed there was adding a new axis/ singleton dimension at the end with `np.newaxis/None`. We are achieving it here with `[...,np.newaxis]` or `[...,None]`.

Thus, another way to have the desired output would be to use a `2D` array version of the scaling array and thus avoid the explicit appending of a new axis, like so -

```
np.dot(images,np.array([[0.299], [0.587], [0.114]]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Divakar, this solved my problem and made my solution so much faster to run :)

Comment: Very nice solution with einsum.